# GTK_IS_WIDGET (child) failed when trying to assign it widgets initialized from a previous function call

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, gtk

I am trying to make my UI code have less calls to gtk_combo_box_text_new(). Initially, I had a for loop that would create and initialize a combo box and then attach it to a grid. However, this would happen every time the parent window is opened and I don't think that this is efficient. I would rather declare and initialize the combo boxes once, and then use them for the lifespan of the program.

Here is my array of pointers to GtkWidget's (in global space):

```
static GtkWidget *apo_combobox[NUM_MPI_MEAS];
```

I have an "init" function that has a conditional block that only runs once (the first time the window is spawned). The problem occurs when I try to declare and initialize my combo boxes in this section.

```
void init_popup() {

  if (!j_first_show) {
    // some code here to create windows and layouts
    // the grid is declared and initialized here as well!!
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // when I place my code to declare and initialize comboboxes in
    // this for loop everything works fine!
    
    apo_combobox[i] = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
    init_combobox(i);

    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(meas_assign.po_grid), apo_combobox[i], 1, j_track_button_placement, 1, 1);
  }
```

The above code shows the flow of code that works. If I do the following, however, I get:

**Gtk-CRITICAL : 10:35:18.106: gtk_grid_attach: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (child)' failed**

```
void init_popup() {

  if (!j_first_show) {
    apo_combobox[i] = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
    init_combobox(i);
    // some code here to create windows and layouts
    // the grid is declared and initialized here as well!!
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // when I place my code to declare and initialize comboboxes in
    // this for loop everything works fine!

    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(meas_assign.po_grid), apo_combobox[i], 1, j_track_button_placement, 1, 1);
  }
```

So, ultimately I am confused why it seems like my array of pointers does not persist through multiple function calls. It works when I first show the popup, but if I hide and reshow the popup, it fails when it is trying to attach my apo_combobox items to the grid.

I already tried printing the memory addresses of each index of apo_combobox but the memory addresses do not change even when the assertion failure begins to happen.

Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Suggestion: make a minimal and reproducible example (one which we could compile and run at home, even inspect). Chances are that by doing so, you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: The actual code base is very large it would be nearly impossible to create an example that people can run from home. I really just needed to explain the structure of the code here because I believe the issue comes from a misunderstanding of what is happening to my array of GtkWidget pointers. But I will use your suggestion in future posts. Like I said though, I dont think it would work for this code. These functions are like 30-100 lines. Thanks though.

Comment: What I have in mind is a simplified example that shows the same problem, not the actual code. If you are lucky, you may find a really dedicated user willing to get into what you have posted. If not, reconsider my suggestion. I have auto-solved innumerable issues by trying to make a small (and reproducible) example for SO...